# Is it possible to change device region from test cases?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, automated-tests, kif

Currently, I have used **KIF** to write test cases for the iOS application. But I the app supports multiple regions and the functionality changes according to the region.
**Is there a way to change device language via KIF**? Or **How can I write and run the test cases for different region?**

Comment: A way is to create different Schemes for your Project. Here you'll be able to set Device language, region etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following in your setup method, but you have to reset the simulator before each run so it's not optimal:

```
override func setUp() {

super.setUp()

continueAfterFailure = false

XCUIApplication().launchArguments += [“-AppleLanguages”, “(fr)”]

XCUIApplication().launchArguments += [“-AppleLocale”, “fr_FR”]

XCUIApplication().launch()
}
```

Comment: I Will try this and update if it works Thanks for your time!